# Video cache not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working with video and image caching in iOS. I have implemented image cache. Now in same cache i want to store the video also i have following code for storing image and video into the cache:

```
-(void)cacheFromURL:(Food*)foodForUrl
{
AppDelegate *app=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[app.imageCache setCountLimit:50];
NSURL *imageUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:foodForUrl.image];
NSURL *videoUrl=[NSURL URLWithString:foodForUrl.video];
UIImage* newImage = [cache objectForKey:imageUrl.description];

if( !newImage )
{
    NSError *err = nil;

    if(imageUrl!=Nil)
    {
        newImage=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl options:0 error:&err]];
    }

    if(videoUrl!=Nil)
    {
        moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:videoUrl];
        [app.imageCache setObject:moviePlayer forKey:videoUrl.description];
        NSLog(@"video caching....%@",videoUrl.description);
    }

    if( newImage )
    {
        [app.imageCache setObject:newImage forKey:imageUrl.description];
        NSLog(@"caching....");
    }
    else
    {
    }
}
}
```

I have following code for retrieving from the cache. It is working for the image but its not  working for the video:

```
- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender 
{
    AppDelegate *app=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:food.video];
    NSLog(@"cached for:%@",url.description);
    moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]init];
//    moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:food.video]];
    moviePlayerController=[app.imageCache objectForKey:url.description];
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    moviePlayerController.view.frame=CGRectMake(320,200, 320,200);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [moviePlayerController play];

}
```

What is problem with playing video in this case? Any answers and suggestions will be valuable

Answer (score 0):

Your method is open to many critical bugs.

1. You use a memory cache to cache media. If the cache becomes full, what happens? If you are using NSCache, the video may be removed before you access it.
2. Are you aware you can only have one video playing at one time? Read [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
3. There is no point to what you are doing. You create a MPMoviePlayerController and then leave it until some later time. I recommend you profile your app resource usage, I think you will find this is not the lightest operation. This may cause indirect bugs.

To me, you seem to be trying to do something that is not very useful. If you can edit the question to explain what exactly you are trying to do, we may be able to help more. Otherwise, as it is, the question is asking us to solve an implementation bug in a design that is poor. You will get a bad answer (like this one) and you will not accept and your accept rate will drop and you will not get future answers. I hope this is helpful for you, I know it is hard at the beginning but try and explain:

1. What your problem is? (the big picture)
2. What you tried?
3. What went wrong?

For this question, you seem to have missed step 1.

Comment: I am taking some image and videos from the web.I want to load the web data into cache in background and retrieve it as required. Its working for image caching ?then whats wrong with video caching. Should i use new cache for video?

Comment: You aren't caching the video. You are saving a pointer a MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: You are saving the image data itself.